# Is Arne the original target of The Occultist?

Tags: the-conjuring-3, the-conjuring-universe

In the 2021 movie *The Conjuring: The Devil Made Me Do It*, a priest named Kastner explains the strategy of The Occultist, the villain of the movie.

> He says she is following a dark ritual that involves a triangle of victims: The Child, The Lover and The Man of God. Each must commit a murder and then commit suicide to complete the ritual. When looking at the people who get possessed throughout the movie, it's evident Ed Warren is **The Man of God**, as he relies on God's powers to battle evil. And we can deduce that, the teenager Jessica who killed her friend Katie and then killed herself symbolizes **The Child**.

So who is **The Lover**? Arne. But, there's a problem. Because Arne is not the one who gets originally possessed. The second Witch's Totem is placed under the Gletzel house and Arne's brother-in-law, the kid David Gletzel was the one who got possessed first. Then it gets passed to Arne, after he demands the demon to leave David alone and possess him instead. And it's unlikely that David symbolizes The Lover (he is still a child). But Arne fits the description because he's in a relationship with David's sister.

So it raises the question, has The Occultist always planned **Arne to be the intended target the second Witch's Totem**?

Comment: Just watched the movie, maybe David was meant to be The Child? And perhaps Ed is The Lover (Lorraine does mention something along the lines of "she thought our love was our weakness"). It seemed like The Occultist had a specific interest in Arne (the photo on the alter) but no real reason for it. There's a lot left unexplained, at least on the first watch

Comment: @fez Good speculation, but who is the Man of God? The teenager from Massachusetts does not fit that description, right?